# Не создается C++ проект на UE5.1

Tags: c++, unreal-engine, unreal-engine-5

**Unreal Engine 5.1**

При создании любго игрового проекта на C++:

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.1/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/foton/UE5Projects/MyFPS1/person3trd2127387a/person3trd2127387a.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/foton/UE5Projects/MyFPS1/person3trd2127387a/person3trd2127387a.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
"dotnet" ?? ?? ???७??? ??? ???譥?
????????, ?ᯮ??塞?? ?ணࠬ??? ??? ?????? 䠩???.
```

Вопрос в чем проблема и как это исправить. В Visual Studio 2022 установил все для разработки игр на C++

Answer (score 1):

У меня так же было, откатись до 5.0.3 и вместо знаков вопроса у тебя будут ссылки на то что тебе надо скачать что бы все исправилось(не помню что именно) и скачай в Visual Studio Installer все связанное с .NET, мне помогло, по крайней мере для 5.0.3, надеюсь помог

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core 6 версии нужна - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64 . А чтобы дальше каракули не показывались - переключи в эпике и unreal язык с русского на английский